# Generate a sound (not from a file)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit

I'm building a small game prototype, and I'd like to be able to play simple sounds whose length/tone/pitch will vary based on what the user is doing.

This is surprisingly hard to do. Closest resource I found was:

http://www.tmroyal.com/playing-sounds-in-swift-audioengine.html

But this does not actually generate any sound on my device or on the iOS simulator.

Does anyone know of any working code to play ANY procedurally generated audio? Simple Sine Wave would do.

Comment: you can use a small sample and vary its properties, that's what most "flexible" sound engines do. Audio synthesis is far from trivial and will never sound as good as one base on an audio sample.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/rgcottrell/5b876d9c5eea4c9e411c

This code on the other hand works, and it's beautifully written...

Success!

Comment: Hi Harry, this project I helped work on may also be of use to you: https://github.com/audiokit/SpaceCannon

It uses AudioKit (http://audiokit.io) to generate synthesized audio events based on sprite kit game events.

Comment: Thanks @narner I'll have a look. To whomever downvoted my answer... you're silly. That code is the only one I've found on the net and it works for me. Accepting my own answer.

Comment: Hope it works out Harry. Also, in regards to the comment on your question: while sound synthesis is indeed far from trivial, the idea that only sample modification will sound good is completely subjective.

Comment: @HarryMexican if you put the frequency to a high value let's say 20000hz, can you hear lots of noises?

Comment: Can you include essential points right into your questions? Linked content tend to disappear without trace. And without linked content your answer is useless.

Comment: would be great to have an updated Swift5 Version of that file (there is one in one of the forks, but I mean the original)

Answer (score 9):

You can try [AudioKit](http://audiokit.io/).

It's an audio framework built on top of `Core Audio`.
In their [Continuous Control](http://audiokit.io/examples/ContinuousControl/) example they use a simple FM oscillator with controlled parameters.

Comment: I'm actually one of the AudioKit developers; really glad you like it!

Comment: Anyway to chain up some Oscillators or even play them by a duration. I would like get a pattern into my sounds.